# strange coldfusion errors after ms sql server table change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am working with ColdFusion 9 on a Windows Server, using MS SQL Server 2005. I am encountering a strange issue.

I am creating an object by querying a table in the database, getting the necessary info, and building the object from the results. So if my table has these columns:

```
id
name
address
```

I am creating an object with methods such as get_id(), get_name(), get_address(), etc. All this works fine and when I query those methods I get the results I expect.

But now I go in and change the table. I add a new column, such as "city". All is ok, the object still instantiates. But now I go in and put some data into that new column. Now my object instantiation no longer functions. I am getting generic errors like this:

```
element ADDRESS is undefined in instance
```

I notice that I still have cftry tags wrapped around the cfquery statement, so I take those off. Now I see this error:

```
unsupported data conversion
```

So I go to the database and I delete the new column completely. Now everything works correctly, as before. So it seems that when I add a new column to this table, SQL Server is trying to do some sort of data conversion on it? I don't see where I have that flagged to happen anywhere.

Any help that can be given will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is that cfc inheriting from another cfc, the errors might be happening there.

Comment: I posted what I think might be the right answer below, but we really need more information to make a good determination of the problem. What's the code on the line that's throwing the error? How is your SQL constructed? How are your methods generated (manually, onMissingTemplate())? The more information the better.

Comment: @Dan - your answer regarding SELECT * was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to make sure that your query isn't using SELECT * to get the columns. SQL server can cache the execution plans and not return columns that have been added if you're using SELECT *.

Another way to fix it is to simply add a line break, or anything else, into the query so that SQL server will create a new execution plan.

Either way, stay away from SELECT *, as it's less performant, and can definitely lead to issues like this.

Comment: That was the issue, I was using SELECT *. Thanks very much!